# Auto-layout features not working in a table view cell in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making a simple app since I'm quite new to xCode. I have a table view which holds cells. I've added constraints that I was hoping would dynamically change the width of the cell depending on the device (iphone vs iPad). However, it doesn't seem to be working.

I believe I've set all the necessary constraints, but I guess I must be missing some.

Here is an image of what I'm working with:

[image: View]

And this is the problem, when I change the size of the device I'm working on, the labels in the cell don't resize themselves.

[image: View2]

Here are the constraints I'm currently using:

[image: Constraints]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you haven't updated the frames after changing the size of the view controller
[image]

Comment: Wow, that was much easier than I expected. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If it worked, consider marking this answer as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: It was making me wait 2 minutes for some reason.